# Can i use the same properties for different classes?

Tags: c#, class, methods, properties, accessor

I'm supposed to find the classes and their responsibilities from the problem statement.

The bank offers the following type of accounts to its customers: savings account, checking account, and money market account. customers are allowed to withdraw (decrease) and deposit (increase) money into those accounts.

my question is:

Can I create 3 different classes that use the same 2 properties (increase and decrease)? Also, would it work for the above scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can. Just try, and iterate your solution. This is basic OO-programming situation and you learn only by doing. If there is problem with i.e compiling your code, just see what compiler says and search from google if needed.

Comment: Yes, you could create 3 identical classes. You could also use a single class, since the given information defines them as having the same methods (`Deposit(int amount)` and `Withdraw(int amount)`, and it could have an enum property that defines the account type. I'm not recommending this, just stating that there is definitely more than one way to derive classes from the given information.

Comment: ...or you could just use one class with a Type property indicating whether it is savings, checking, or MM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? You could create one parent class with that properties and get inherited by child classes. Also you can create interface and implement custom logic for each class you want to have such property.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Increase { get; set; }
    public int Decrease { get; set; }
}

public class Child1 : Parent
{

}

public class Child2 : Parent
{

}
```